# Multiprocessing Python - Python exit suddenly but the program still continue

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I become a bit crazy about using multiprocessing in Python.
Let me explain briefly.

I have a directory of images. And images are insides categories. I have in total ten categories and dozens of images per categories.

Briefly, the goal of my program is to take randomly three images per category and performs a big computation, ten times corresponding to ten different parameters.

The programs works well but it takes time. That's why I would like to parallelize it using multiprocessing.

The aim is to be able to use my 10 cores, to have in each core, a computation using one parameter.

I have a big function which has two for-loop.

Here the main file :

```
def main():
    #Array which contains the 10 parameters to tests
    parameters = ['param1','param2',...,'param10']
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2) #I put a small number in purpose
    params = (list_of_random_objects, trained_dataset, name_dataset)
    #List of randoms objects is an array [('category_i', ['path_image_1', 'path_image_2','path_image_2'])]
    #trained_dataset is a path and name_dataset is the name of the dataset
    func = partial(automatic_processing, params)
    pool.map(func, parameters)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here the big function (I let the most important part) :

```
def automatic_processing(params,name_parameter):
    list_of_random_objects, trained_dataset, name_dataset = params

    #First loop : for each category
     for idx, object_list_category in enumerate(list_of_random_objects):
         print("\n =====> Processing current category  : {} <===== ".format(object_list_category[0]))

         #Second loop : for each objects of the current category
         for obj in object_list_category[1]:
             print("\n ###### Processing current OBJECT : {} \n".format(obj))

            #Do some processing (Big computation which take a lot of times)

         ///CRASH HERE
         #Drawing result second loop with matplotlib

     #Drawing result first loop with matplotlib
```

So the program is working but at the end of the first loop, I have a pop up message saying that "Python crash suddenly". The programs continue to run.

I have notice some things that may give you a hint about my issue.

- If I comment the drawing part, it works
- It I let the drawing part, my programs stop after the first three objets of the category and continue with the same three objects. It's like the my first loop is stuck on the fist item indefinitely.

For the drawing part, I use Matplotlib.

Here the error, I obtained from the report.

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000110
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x110:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000102081000-0000000102083000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Application Specific Information:
*** multi-threaded process forked ***
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff94c8c041 _dispatch_root_queue_push_override + 204
1   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff94f097ae _xpc_connection_activate_if_needed + 227
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff94efc5ba xpc_connection_resume + 64
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff7f6913fb -[_CFXPreferences _copyDaemonConnectionSettingUpIfNecessaryForRole:] + 427
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff7f691487 -[_CFXPreferences withConnectionForRole:performBlock:] + 23
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff7f6619f7 __80-[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:]_block_invoke + 199
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff7f661842 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:] + 226
```

Could you please help ? Did I do something wrong ?

Thank

Comment: In your inner loop, was `object_list_category[1]` intentional?

Comment: Also, let me offer some advice that may potentially lead you to finding your own bug. It seems like you have a good grasp of how multithreading / parallel processing works, but just keep in mind that when you're mapping elements through a function, it's best to think of it like a data transformation. The function defines the change to apply, and the iterable is the input that gets changed into the output. It seems like your function _might_ be trying to iterate over your list, but you should be letting the mapping do that for you...

Comment: @Peri461 yes it's intentional. As it's a tuple, I just want to accees to the second item which correspond to my images.
I understand what you say but as I have already an iterable which correspond to my parameters, I would to test. How can perform the two loop inside my function ?

Comment: @lilouch What is the exact error message (traceback)? I suppose it's not _"Python crash suddenly"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got crazy but finally I found the solution.

It turns out that I needed to add this following line after importing Matplotlib:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

I used to activate this line only on the server as it doesn't have a display for drawing but it seems that I need to activate also this line when I do some parallelization.

Now It works !